# How to treat empty documents in an stm topic model

Tags: r, quanteda

Through a process like this:

```
library(quanteda)
library(stm)

dftest <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500", "unusual", "It is a long established fact that a reader", "Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is"))
  
testDfm <- dftest$text %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
    dfm() %>% dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 2)

stmmodel <- stm(documents = testDfm, K = 2)

quant_stm <- convert(testDfm, to = "stm")

results<- data.frame(quant_stm$meta,
                      maxtopic = apply(stmmodel$theta,1,which.max))
```

I receive this warning:

```
stmmodel <- stm(documents = testDfm, K = 2)
Warning messages:
1: In dfm2stm(x, docvars, omit_empty = TRUE) :
  Dropped empty document(s): text2
2: In stm(documents = testDfm, K = 2) :
  K=2 is equivalent to a unidimensional scaling model which you may prefer.
```

How is it possible to handle the dropped empty documents in order to receive in the results a dataframe with the id column number of input dataframe dftest and the number of topic of stm?

Comment: You simply want the rows of `results` to match those of `dftest`, and the `maxtopic` to equal `NA` for that row?

Answer (score 4):

Try substituting this for the end of your code.

By reassigning the docnames, you ensure that this will be passed through to the stm functions:

```r
docnames(testDfm) <- dftest$id

stmmodel <- stm(documents = testDfm, K = 2)
quant_stm <- convert(testDfm, to = "stm")
## Warning in dfm2stm(x, docvars, omit_empty = TRUE): Dropped empty document(s): 2
```

Now create the results so that you can merge on `id`.  This comes from the `documents` list element of `quant_stm`, but needs conversion back to integer from its `character` (as a name of the list elements in `quant_stm$documents`):

```r
results <- data.frame(
  id = as.integer(names(quant_stm$documents)),
  maxtopic = apply(stmmodel$theta, 1, which.max)
)
```

Then you can merge them back and put them into the original order:

```r
library(dplyr)
right_join(results, dftest) %>%
  select(-text) %>%
  arrange(id)
## Joining, by = "id"
##   id maxtopic
## 1  1        2
## 2  2       NA
## 3  3        1
## 4  4        1
```